# CSS help required for border animation

Tags: html, css

Here is my code:

```css
.section-one {
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
}
.section-one h2 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "AzoSans-Medium";
}
.section-one p {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "AzoSans-Regular";
}
.section-one .boxes {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 75px;
}
.section-one .boxes:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}
.section-one .boxes .left-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}
.section-one .boxes .left-box img {
  width: 100%;
}
.section-one .boxes .right-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}
.section-one .boxes .right-box.left:before,
.section-one .boxes .right-box.left::after {
  left: 0px;
  right: -30px;
}
.section-one .boxes .right-box:before,
.section-one .boxes .right-box::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 50px;
  left: -30px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: -2;
}
.section-one .boxes .right-box:before {
  border: 1px solid #f29d1f;
}


.section-one .boxes .right-box.left h2 {
  text-align: left;
}


/**updated starts**/
.section-one .boxes .right-box.left:before,
.section-one .boxes .right-box.left::after {
  left: 0px;
  right: -30px;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box.left:before {
  /* left: 0px;
  right: -30px; */
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 250px 0px 0px 250px;
}
/**updated ends**/

/** purely new code starts**/
.section-one .boxes .right-box::after {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box.left::after {
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 75%;
  background-size: calc(50% + 30px) 100%, 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat, no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, red), linear-gradient(red, red);
  animation: left 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  /* just to give time to go full screen on SO snippet! */
}

@keyframes left {
  0% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, red), linear-gradient(red, red);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  49.99% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, red), linear-gradient(red, red);
  }
  50% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      linear-gradient(red, red);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  99.99% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      linear-gradient(red, red);
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
/** purely new code ends**/

.section-one .boxes .right-box.right h2 {
  text-align: right;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box.right:before {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0px 250px 250px 0px;
}

/* probably code where to look starts */
.section-one .boxes .right-box.right::after {
  background-position: 0 0, 0 75%;
  background-size: calc(50% + 30px) 100%, 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat, no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(lime, lime), linear-gradient(lime, lime);
  animation: right 5s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

@keyframes right {
  0% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(lime, lime), linear-gradient(lime, lime);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  49.99% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(lime, lime), linear-gradient(lime, lime);
  }
  50% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      linear-gradient(lime, lime);
    transform: translateX(50%);
  }
  99.99% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent),
      linear-gradient(lime, lime);
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}
/* probably code where to look ends */

.section-one .boxes .right-box h2 {
  padding: 50px 0px 20px 0px;
}
.section-one .boxes .right-box p {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 355px;
  text-align: justify;
}
.section-one .boxes .action-btn {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}
@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .section-one h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .section-one p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 75px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box:before {
    left: -30px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box.left h2 {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box.left:before {
    border-radius: 200px 0px 0px 200px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box.right h2 {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box.right:before {
    border-radius: 0px 200px 200px 0px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box h2 {
    padding: 50px 0px 15px 0px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box p {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 355px;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .action-btn {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .section-one h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }

  .section-one .boxes .right-box.left:before {
    left: 0px;
    right: -15px;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
  }

  .section-one .boxes .right-box h2 {
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box p {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
    padding: 0px 15px 30px 30px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .action-btn {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<section class="section-one">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">
      
        <div class="boxes">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 aos-init" data-aos="zoom-in-right" data-aos-duration="800">
              <div class="right-box left">
                <h2>Heading1.</h2>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla in erat et quam semper convallis. Phasellus vel nisl id leo suscipit molestie. Sed nec dignissim urna. Donec sit amet tortor nulla. Etiam tempus dui id ipsum commodo, et laoreet tortor luctus.
                  Ut dapibus.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 aos-init" data-aos="zoom-in-left" data-aos-duration="800">
              <div class="left-box">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x430" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        <div class="boxes">
          <div class="row flex-row-reverse">
            <div
                 class="col-lg-6"
                 data-aos="zoom-in"
                 data-aos-duration="800"
                 >
              <div class="right-box right">
                <h2>Heading 2.</h2>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.
                  Nulla in erat et quam semper convallis. Phasellus vel nisl
                  id leo suscipit molestie. Sed nec dignissim urna. Donec
                  sit amet tortor nulla. Etiam tempus dui id ipsum commodo,
                  et laoreet tortor luctus. Ut dapibus.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div
                 class="col-lg-6"
                 data-aos="zoom-in"
                 data-aos-duration="800"
                 >
              <div class="left-box">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x430" class="img-fluid" alt="">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>
        
        
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Here, I am trying to do border animation by covering up the border with a layer and then moving that layer in a specific way so that the border shows up slowly and smoothly.

Here, the border cover with red layer is working fine, as it slowly uncovers the border, (to view the actual intended animation, you might need to change that red color to white)

Similar, to that I am trying to animate the section with red layer (Heading 2 section), but there the moment is little wrong with that small lime layer,

1. actually it should have to be moved in the `blue` marked box area but it is currently moving in `red` marked box area. This is also showing in image below.
2. Probably its positioning incorrectly, because initially I feel its top left corner should be aligned to left corner of blue box

Long story short, I want that lime layer to be animated correctly in similar fashion to that red, but they are in different direction.

[image]

JSFIDDLE: https://jsfiddle.net/csgwutjp/1/ Please, view it by increasing the window size, as in attached image.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When animating the right hand side border we need to swap the 'mask' that is being moved over it around, so that the part that covers the whole border is to the right and the shorter part that covers just the bottom half is to the left.

In doing that we also have to change positioning and transitions to match.

```css
.section-one {
  position: relative;
  background: #ffffff;
}

.section-one h2 {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 32px;
  margin: 0px 0px 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "AzoSans-Medium";
}

.section-one p {
  color: #000000;
  font-size: 16px;
  margin: 10px 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  font-family: "AzoSans-Regular";
}

.section-one .boxes {
  position: relative;
  margin-top: 75px;
}

.section-one .boxes:last-child {
  margin-bottom: 100px;
}

.section-one .boxes .left-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
  z-index: 3;
}

.section-one .boxes .left-box img {
  width: 100%;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box {
  position: relative;
  margin: 25px 0px 0px 0px;
  height: 100%;
  z-index: 2;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box.left:before,
.section-one .boxes .right-box.left::after {
  left: 0px;
  right: -30px;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box:before,
.section-one .boxes .right-box::after {
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  top: 50px;
  left: -30px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 25px;
  z-index: -2;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box:before {
  border: 1px solid #f29d1f;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box.left h2 {
  text-align: left;
}


/**updated starts**/

.section-one .boxes .right-box.left:before {
  left: 0px;
  right: -30px;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box.left::after {
  right: 0px;
  /* turned round */
  left: -30px;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box.left:before {
  /* left: 0px;
      right: -30px; */
  border-right: none;
  border-radius: 250px 0px 0px 250px;
}


/**updated ends**/


/** purely new code starts**/

.section-one .boxes .right-box::after {
  width: 200%;
  height: 100%;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box.left::after {
  background-position: 0 0, 100% 75%;
  background-size: calc(50% + 30px) 100%, 50% 50%;
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat, no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(red, red), linear-gradient(red, red);
  animation: left 1s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 1s;
  /* just to give time to go full screen on SO snippet! */
}

@keyframes left {
  0% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, red), linear-gradient(red, red);
    transform: translateX(0);
  }
  49.99% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(red, red), linear-gradient(red, red);
  }
  50% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(red, red);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  99.99% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(transparent, transparent), linear-gradient(red, red);
    transform: translateX(0);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/** purely new code ends**/

.section-one .boxes .right-box.right h2 {
  text-align: right;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box.right:before {
  border-left: none;
  border-radius: 0px 250px 250px 0px;
}


/* probably code where to look starts */

.section-one .boxes .right-box.right::after {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  width: calc(200% + 60px);
  left: -30px;
  transform: translateX(-50%);
  background-position: 0 75%, right 0;
  /* turned round */
  background-size: 50% 50%, 50% 100%;
  /* turned round */
  background-repeat: no-repeat no-repeat, no-repeat no-repeat;
  background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(white, white);
  animation: right 5s ease-in-out;
  animation-fill-mode: forwards;
  animation-delay: 5s;
}

@keyframes right {
  0% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(white, white);
    transform: translateX(-50%);
  }
  49.99% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(white, white);
  }
  50% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
    /* turned round */
    transform: translateX(0px);
  }
  99.99% {
    background-image: linear-gradient(white, white), linear-gradient(transparent, transparent);
    /* turned round */
    transform: translateX(-50%);
    opacity: 1;
  }
  100% {
    opacity: 0;
  }
}


/* probably code where to look ends */

.section-one .boxes .right-box h2 {
  padding: 50px 0px 20px 0px;
}

.section-one .boxes .right-box p {
  display: block;
  margin: 15px auto;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 355px;
  text-align: justify;
}

.section-one .boxes .action-btn {
  position: relative;
  text-align: right;
}

@media (max-width: 1199px) {
  .section-one h2 {
    font-size: 28px;
  }
  .section-one p {
    font-size: 15px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 50px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 75px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box:before {
    left: -30px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box.left h2 {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box.left:before {
    border-radius: 200px 0px 0px 200px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box.right h2 {
    text-align: left;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box.right:before {
    border-radius: 0px 200px 200px 0px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box h2 {
    padding: 50px 0px 15px 0px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box p {
    display: block;
    margin: 15px auto;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 355px;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .action-btn {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
  }
}

@media (max-width: 991px) {
  .section-one h2 {
    font-size: 25px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes {
    position: relative;
    margin-top: 10px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes:last-child {
    margin-bottom: 30px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box.left:before {
    left: 0px;
    right: -15px;
    border-right: none;
    border-radius: 100px 0px 0px 100px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box h2 {
    padding: 0px 0px 15px 0px;
    margin: 0px;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .right-box p {
    display: block;
    margin: 0px auto 15px auto;
    padding: 0px 15px 30px 30px;
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 100%;
    text-align: justify;
  }
  .section-one .boxes .action-btn {
    position: relative;
    text-align: right;
  }
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/font-awesome/4.7.0/css/font-awesome.min.css">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<section class="section-one">
  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-lg-12">

        <div class="boxes">
          <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-6 aos-init" data-aos="zoom-in-right" data-aos-duration="800">
              <div class="right-box left">
                <h2>Heading1.</h2>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla in erat et quam semper convallis. Phasellus vel nisl id leo suscipit molestie. Sed nec dignissim urna. Donec sit amet tortor nulla. Etiam tempus dui id ipsum commodo, et laoreet tortor luctus.
                  Ut dapibus.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6 aos-init" data-aos="zoom-in-left" data-aos-duration="800">
              <div class="left-box">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x430" class="img-fluid" alt="">
              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>

        <div class="boxes">
          <div class="row flex-row-reverse">
            <div class="col-lg-6" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-duration="800">
              <div class="right-box right">
                <h2>Heading 2.</h2>
                <p>
                  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Nulla in erat et quam semper convallis. Phasellus vel nisl id leo suscipit molestie. Sed nec dignissim urna. Donec sit amet tortor nulla. Etiam tempus dui id ipsum commodo, et laoreet tortor luctus.
                  Ut dapibus.
                </p>
              </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-lg-6" data-aos="zoom-in" data-aos-duration="800">
              <div class="left-box">
                <img src="https://via.placeholder.com/650x430" class="img-fluid" alt="">

              </div>
            </div>
          </div>
        </div>


      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>


<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.4.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.3.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>animation
```